# Плавный скролл к якорю на другой странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте хочу реализовать плавный скролл к блоку расположенному на другой странице.

Для плавного скролла по текущей странице использую следующий код:

```
  function handler(event) {
    var hash = event.target.hash;
    var headerHeight = $('header').height();

    if (hash) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var tag = $(hash);

      if ($(hash).length) {
        var offset = tag.offset().top - headerHeight;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: offset},'slow');
      }
    }
  }

  $('.main-nav a').on( "click", handler );
```

Если я указываю ссылку на другую страницу такого формата 
Происходит переход, и резкий скачок  к блоку с id.  Как сделать это скачок плавным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо на той, странице, куда осуществляется переход, разместить скрипт, который по хешу будет скроллить к нужному блоку. Что-то типа:

```
var myHash = location.hash; //получаем значение хеша
location.hash = ''; //очищаем хеш
if(myHash[1] != undefined){ //проверяем, есть ли в хеше какое-то значение
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(myHash).offset().top}, 500); //скроллим за полсекунды
};
```

Comment: humster_spb, спасибо вам огроменное! прям выручили!!!!

Comment: `var myHash = location.hash; //получаем значение хеша location.hash = ''; //очищаем хеш if(myHash[1] != undefined){ //проверяем, есть ли в хеше какое-то значение $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(myHash).offset().top}, 500); //скроллим за полсекунды };`
@humster_spb, а без очистки хэша при загрузке страница происходит дерганный переход к нужному элементу. Поправить это можно как-либо?

Answer (score 0):

у меня это сработало в режиме неавторизованого пользователя(на Друпале)

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
  });
  Drupal.behaviors.script = {
if (window.location.hash)
        scroll(0,0);
// takes care of some browsers issue
      setTimeout(function(){scroll(0,0);},1);


//your current click function
      $('.services', context).click(function () {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 'px'
          },1000,'swing');
        });

// if we have anchor on the url (calling from other page)
        if(window.location.hash){
          // smooth scroll to the anchor id
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop:$(window.location.hash).offset().top + 'px'
          },1000,'swing');
        }
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я пытался сделать переход на другую страницу к определенному разделу на ней с помощью хеша в ссылке:    ( ... / { article.link } # { article.id } )

Для этого нужно было воспользоваться методом - getBoundingClientRect() который
возвращает объект DOMRect, предоставляющий информацию о положении необходимого элемента относительно viewport.

Но если на конечной странице много контента, то getBoundingClientRect() срабатывает быстрее чем загружается контент, в итоге скролл не доходит до нужного раздела.

В итоге я смог решить это тем, что поставил таймауты и на getBoundingClientRect() и на скролл до элемента.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (articles.length === 0) return; // Ждем загрузки артиклов
    const hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); // забираем хэш из пути
    const scrollElement = document.getElementById(hash);
    if (scrollElement) {
      setTimeout(()=>{            //(1)
        const { top } = scrollElement.getBoundingClientRect();
             setTimeout(() => {   //(2)
        window.scrollTo({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          top: top + (window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop) - 100,
        });
      }, 300); //(2)Ставим делэй на скролл
      },300) //(1)Ставим делэй на получение getBoundingClientRect
    }
  }, [articles]);
```