# Как сделать плавный скрол к якорю на нативном JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте подскажите как вот такое написать на чистом JavaScript

```js
 function showSection(section, isAnimate) {
  var
  direction = section.replace(/#/, ''),
  reqSection = $('section').filter('[data-section="' + direction + '"]');
  if (reqSection.length) {
   var reqSectionPos = reqSection.offset().top;
  }

  if (isAnimate) {
   $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: reqSectionPos}, 500);
  } else {
   $('body, html').scrollTop(reqSectionPos);
  }
 };

 $('.menu-link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  showSection($(this).attr('href'), true);
 });

 showSection(window.location.hash, false);

 $(window).scroll(function(){
  checkSection();
 });

 function checkSection(){
  $('.s-section').each(function(){
   var
    $this = $(this),
    topEdge = $this.offset().top - 200,
    bottomEdge = topEdge + $this.height(),
    wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (topEdge < wScroll && bottomEdge > wScroll) {
    var
     currentId = $this.data('section'),
     reqLink = $('.menu-link').filter('[href="#' + currentId + '"]');
     reqLink.closest('.menu-item').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
     window.location.hash = currentId
   }
  });
 };
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Плавный скролл к якорю на другой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735098/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb-%d0%ba-%d1%8f%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5)

Comment: мне надо на чистом JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time, prop) {
    if (!elem) {
        return;
    }
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
            if (prop) {
                elem[style] = (from + step * (to - from))+unit;
            } else {
                elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from))+unit;
            }
            if (step === 1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 25);
    if (prop) {
       elem[style] = from+unit;
    } else {
       elem.style[style] = from+unit;
    }
}

function scrollToElement(id) {
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    animate(document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement, "scrollTop", "", 0, target.offsetTop, 2000, true);
}

window.onload = function () {
    // скроллим к блоку с id "div6"
    scrollToElement("div6");
};
```

```css
div {
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">asdf1</div>
<div id="div2">asdf2</div>
<div id="div3">asdf3</div>
<div id="div4">asdf4</div>
<div id="div5">asdf5</div>
<div id="div6">asdf6</div>
<div id="div7">asdf7</div>
<div id="div8">asdf8</div>
<div id="div9">asdf9</div>
<div id="div10">asdf10</div>
```