# Плавный скрол к якорю на новой странице

Tags: javascript, html

```
$('.menu-item-1689').on('click', function() {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.kol-scrol').offset().top+"px"},{duration:1E3});
});
$('.menu-item-1690').on('click', function() {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.pr-scrol').offset().top+"px"},{duration:1E3});
});
$('.menu-item-1691').on('click', function() {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.dost-scrol').offset().top+"px"},{duration:1E3});
});
$('.menu-item-1692').on('click', function() {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.onas-scrol').offset().top+"px"},{duration:1E3});
});
$('.menu-item-1693').on('click', function() {
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.kont-scrol').offset().top+"px"},{duration:1E3});
});
```

---

Выше мой код по клику на класс .menu-item-1689 пользователя переносит на  место с классом .kol-scrol и т.д. Но если мы находимся на другой странице ничего не работает. Знаю, что нужно использовать хеш, не знаю, как. Видел вот эту статью: [Плавный скролл к якорю на другой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735098/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb-%d0%ba-%d1%8f%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5) но не смог адаптировать свой код. Где-то я не прав. Покажите, как должно быть, пожалуйста.